# Open Football (Soccer) Player Valuation Database

Tags: data-request, football

I'm looking for an open database of football player valuation.
From transfermarket, the closest I got is this:

https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/marktwertkarriereende/marktwertetop?position=&land_id=0&plus=1

However it is quite limited in size (only has 250 players on it).

I'm OK with other variables but the variables I'm most interested in are:

- Player Name
- Max Valuation
- Player Position

Comment: Just narrow down the query to a specific position or country.

Comment: @dly That's a lot of queries to be able to get to a reasonably large database (e.g., http://c3420952.r52.cf0.rackcdn.com/playerdata.xml). Also, that particular valuation is for retired players, what about current players ?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for then? If you chose to display that table I suppose you were looking for retired players. Other options can be found in the dropdown menu (Market values).. (like https://www.transfermarkt.com/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop for the most valuable ones right now). The queries on that website will always be limited to 10 pages of 25 players, though.

Answer (score 0):

This would be hard to provide as an open database because the player values and poroperties are quite dynamic.

But, consider creating your own, which can be refreshed as often as you like.

Check out one of the many scraping code snippets, for example:

https://fcpython.com/blog/introduction-scraping-data-transfermarkt